# Jenkins build fails with "Non-resolvable parent POM"

Tags: maven, jenkins

We need to setup a Jenkins build task for our Maven based project. I've created such a task on our central Jenkins and it runs successfully.

Now, I need to do some serious refactoring of the build infrastructure and in order to do that I need to experiment with Jenkins. I don't want to overload our central Jenkins, so I've installed Jenkins locally, on my machine. It's the same version as the central Jenkins - 1.617. The difference is that the central Jenkins runs on a Linux machine and I have Windows 8. I've setup my local Jenkins to use the same Maven installation (v.3.2.5), I'm using to run the local Maven build from the console.

The problem is that the build doesn't go thru. I'm getting errors like:

**[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact aaa.ssdd:ssdd-parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 10**

All the posts on the I-net suggest that I explicitly point the parent relative path, which I don't want to do, because the pom.xml files are fine (Remember - build goes thru on the central Jenkins.) Even if I change the pom.xmls and resolve these errors, I'm running into another:

**ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.IllegalStateException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SSDD\modules\aaa.ssdd$SSDD\builds\53 already existed; will not overwite with SSDD/aaa.ssdd:SSDD #53
    at hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:189)
    at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:178)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1017)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModule.newBuild(MavenModule.java:392)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:700)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)**

Like I said - none of this happens with the central Jenkins. Why is it acting so differently from the central build? Is it possible that something Windows specific is causing the problem?

Does anybody have a clue, what are the eventual reasons and how can I resolve the errors without changing the pom.xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be platform independent problem - on Mac OS it generates the same errors.

The solution was to downgrade to an older version of Jenkins - 1.575. Seems that if, after that, Jenkins is upgraded to v.1.6xx, it works fine. That's why it works on our central Jenkins, which is v.1.617. For now, I plan to stick with v.1.575. Tested it, with Maven v.3.1.1 and v.3.2.5 - works fine.